# SELECT statement with an explicit list of columns and then an asterisk (*)

Tags: oracle

SQL Server allows to use SELECT statements similar to:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, *
FROM dbo.Customers
```

When I try to execute such a query on Oracle database, I get the following error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Doesn't Oracle support such queries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only if you prefix the asterisk with the table name:

```
select dummy, dual.* from dual;

DUMMY DUMMY 
----- ----- 
X     X
```

Which limits it's use to tables not joined with the `using` syntax:

```
select dummy, d1.* from dual d1 join dual d2 using(dummy)

SQL Error: ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier
25154. 00000 -  "column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier"
*Cause:    Columns that are used for a named-join (either a NATURAL join
           or a join with a USING clause) cannot have an explicit qualifier.
*Action:   Remove the qualifier.

select d2.dummy, d1.* from dual d1 join dual d2 on(d1.dummy=d2.dummy);

DUMMY DUMMY 
----- ----- 
X     X
```

Comment: So when I am joining multiple tables, I need to use `FirstName, LastName, City, Customers.*, Orders.*`, right?

Comment: right - and don't use `using`

Comment: Why does Oracle keep doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of table names you can use aliases

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, c.*
FROM Customers c;
```

Even on SQL server 2008 you get into trouble, when your query evolves

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, *
FROM Customers 
ORDER BY Firstname ;
```

you will have to change it to

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, c.*
FROM Customers c 
ORDER BY c.Firstname ;
```